# Perl - Relative path of a file inside a module

Tags: perl, relative-path, perl-module

I am building up a website using Perl. I organized my files as follow:

- /index.cgi
- /perl/modules/databaseFunctions.pm
- /perl/indexCheck.cgi
- /database/database.xml

Inside **databaseFunctions.pm** I have a function X() that reads and writes on database.xml. In X() I have specified relative path of the database as follow:

```
sub X{
    my $db_path='../../database/database.xml';
    my $parser=XML::LibXML->new();
    my $doc=$parser->parse_file($db_path);
    ....
    ....
 }
```

Here is the problem:
I have to call X() from index.cgi and indexCheck.cgi but I get an error the following error:

```
Could not create file parser context for file "../../database/database.xml": No such file or directory at perl/modules/databaseFunctions.pm line 21.
```

I think the problem is that when I call X() inside index.cgi or inside /perl/indexCheck.cgi the relative path of the database is different but I don't know how to set a path that works for index.cgi and /perl/indexCheck.cgi.

Comment: Relative paths are based on the working directory of the process that is running.  It might be better to use a configuration file that contains the absolute path to your database file so you don't have to care where the program is running..

Comment: I hope you have a `package` statement inside your `databaseFunctions.pm`? It should say `package databaseFunctions`, but package names that start with a lower-case letter are reserved for Perl *pragmas*, so it should properly be `package DatabaseFunctions` in file `DatabaseFunctions.pm`. Personally, I would call it just `Database` as the the "functions" part is implicit

Comment: But please - don't call your function `X`. That's a terrible name to give a variable.

Comment: @Sobrique it was just an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem boils down to "How to find out the path of the current script (*.pl)?" and 
"How to find out the path of the current module (*.pm)?".

### Scripts

For scripts, there is a very convenient module, [`FindBin`](http://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin.html), that offers 4 variables for the current script's name and path with
either symlinks resolved or not. Usually `$FindBin::Bin` is what you are looking for. It's the path of the current script.
I often use it to enhance the `@INC` path so that my scripts find additional (own) modules like so:

```
use FindBin;
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/my_mod_path";
use MyModule;
```

In this case `MyModule.pm` is searched for in the directory `my_mod_path` below the current script's path. Very convenient.

The module is part of the core distribution, i.e. no further installation is neccessary.

### Modules

`FindBin` may not safely be used from inside modules because then it depends who (script or module) makes the first `use FindBin;`.
So if you don't want to care about the order, don't `use FindBin;` in modules, only in scripts.

For modules, there is some trick. Use the perl function [`caller()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html).
Depending on the context called in, it returns the `$filename` of the file where it actually was called.

Thus, in modules you can safely use the following to get the module's path:

```
use File::Basename;
my $path_of_this_module = File::Basename::dirname( eval { ( caller() )[1] } );
```

Given that path you can navigate relative to it in order to find the other files you need, e.g. `"$path_of_this_module/../.."` and so on.

### EDIT

index.cgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use FindBin;
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/perl/modules";
use databaseFunctions;

databaseFunctions::X( "called from index.cgi\n" );
```

perl/indexCheck.cgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use FindBin;
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/modules";
use databaseFunctions;

databaseFunctions::X( "called from indexCheck.cgi\n" );
```

perl/modules/databaseFunctions.pm:

```
package databaseFunctions;

use File::Basename;

my $path_of_this_module = File::Basename::dirname( eval { ( caller() )[1] } );

sub X {
    my $arg = shift;

    my $db_path="$path_of_this_module/../../database/database.xml";

    open(my $fh, '>>', $db_path) or die "cannot open $db_path: $!\n";
    print $fh $arg;
    close($fh);
}

1;
```

When I now call ./index.cgi and then ./perl/indexCheck.cgi, then I get the following:

database/database.xml:

```
called from index.cgi
called from indexCheck.cgi
```

Exactly, what I thought you were looking for.

Comment: Your answer partially solves my problem. With your solution, I use File::Basename inside my module to get the path where the module is called but then, I have to put an "if else" inside my code to tell to the functions where the database is respect of the location where the module is called. The problem is that the module is called by scripts in different folders and the relative path to the database changes every time.

Comment: @KiraLive So then your file `/database/database.xml` is moving around?
I thought from the `/perl/modules/databaseFunctions.pm`'s perspective
it is always located at `../../database/database.xml`. Given that, my proposal works.

Comment: Okay, I missed to use this: <code>$path_of_this_module/../../database/database.xml</code>. Now it works like a charm. Thank you very much.

Comment: @KiraLive Ah, great! You're welcome. I was already wondering why it didn't work for you. As a side note: There's also a Perl constant called `__FILE__`. You can also use that instead of the `eval...caller` stuff, I guess. Cannot remember why I coded it with `caller()`. Perhaps there was a reason, perhaps not. Try out `my $path_of_this_module = File::Basename::dirname( __FILE__ );`. Should have the same effect and doesn't look so frightening. ;-)

Comment: It works perfectly using  <code>__FILE__ </code> instead of caller( ) too. Thank you again.